# Chartjs plugin label in Angular app moving unexpectedly at hover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I have an angular app showing a bar chart using [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) and [angular-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) directive.

I have also a Chartjs plugin applied on the bar chart to add a horizontal line with a label above it.

It appears like this, with a space between the label and the horizontal line:
[image]

But after I hover the mouse over one of the bars in the chart, the label moves a few pixel closer to the line:

[image]

I cannot find out why. Here is the issue reproduced: http://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/JWEeOZ

and the code:

```js
//angular app ----------------------------------------------------------

angular.module('app', ['chart.js'])
.controller('BarCtrl', ['$scope',
  function ($scope) {

  $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  $scope.series = ['Series A'];

  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  ];

    $scope.options = {
                horizontalLine: [{
                  "y": 60,
                  "style": "rgba(255,102,102,0.4)",
                  "text": "Horizontal line"
                }]
            }
}]);

//horizontal line extension for chart.js ------------------------------
var horizonalLinePlugin = {
  afterDraw: function(chartInstance) {

    var yScale = chartInstance.scales["y-axis-0"];
    var canvas = chartInstance.chart;
    var ctx = canvas.ctx;
    var index;
    var line;
    var style;
    var labelSize;

    if (chartInstance.options.horizontalLine) {
      for (index = 0; index < chartInstance.options.horizontalLine.length; index++) {
        line = chartInstance.options.horizontalLine[index];

        if (!line.style) {
          style = "rgba(169,169,169, .6)";
        } else {
          style = line.style;
        }

        if (line.y) {
          yValue = yScale.getPixelForValue(line.y);
        } else {
          yValue = 0;
        }

        ctx.lineWidth = 3;

        if (yValue) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(yScale.width, yValue);
          ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, yValue);
          ctx.strokeStyle = style;
          ctx.stroke();
        }

          if (chartInstance.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.fontSize != undefined){
              labelSize = parseInt(chartInstance.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.fontSize);
          } else {
              labelSize = parseInt(chartInstance.config.options.defaultFontSize);
          }

        if (line.text) {
          ctx.fillStyle = style;
          ctx.fillText(line.text, yScale.width, yValue-labelSize-4);
        }
      }
      return;
    };
  }
};
Chart.pluginService.register(horizonalLinePlugin);
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div style="width:500px; height:300px;" ng-controller="BarCtrl">

<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options">
    </canvas>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried figuring this out for quite some time and came up empty.  Maybe try this plugin instead: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for anyone interested -**

This is happening due to the fact that, ChartJS sets [text­*'s* baseline](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_textbaseline.asp) to **`top`** by default, when hovered over the graph.

To get the correct behavior, you need to set the text­*'s* baseline to **`alphabetic`** before drawing the text, for instance :

```
...
ctx.textBaseline = 'alphabetic';
ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
...
```

Here is the [**working example**](https://codepen.io/gaand/pen/WEMWKL?editors=0010).